# What about a nucleus defines the number and type of orbitals available to an electron?

Tags: electrons, subatomic

I understand the idea electrons are essentially 'wavelets' and that they propagate within an orbital as a wave. And that there can only ever be two 'wavelets' in a single orbital. Each one propagating orthogonally to the other (please forgive my clumsy descriptions).

Further to this, when energy is added to one of the waves propagating within the orbital, it jumps to one of the higher orbitals.

What I'm really looking for is the cause of any given orbital being available to an electron whether incoming or outgoing.

Is it a function of the nucleus? Or something else?

Comment: What do you mean "cause of any given orbital being available"? By definition, the orbitals are the stationary-state solutions of the Schrödinger equation for the given atom. What does it mean for such an orbital to be "available"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind putting it another way, why does one atom have few orbitals and another have many?

Comment: They all have the same amount: Infinitely many, though only finitely many of these are occupied by electrons at any given time. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ACuriousMind so every element has the same orbitals ad infinitum and in a fixed arrangement?

Comment: So, why does any given element have _these_ orbitals in _this_ shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [atomic orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) is a stationary solution to the Schrödinger equation, or, equivalently, an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian.

The Schrödinger equation for a hydrogen atom is
$$ \left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V(r)\right) \psi(x) = E\psi(x),$$
where $\psi(x)$ is the wavefunction that describes the orbital and $V(r)$ the Coulomb potential of the nucleus. The shapes you often see drawn in "pictures of orbitals" are the regions where it exceeds a certain threshhold.

We can actually solve this equation analytically and give expressions for $\psi(x)$. For other atoms, it gets more complicated - the nucleus gets a higher charge, which would not be all that difficult to deal with, but also you will have *more than one electron* in a typical neutral atom, so you also have to take into account the repulsive Coulomb potential of each electron. Like the three-body problem in classical mechanics, this quickly gets unsolvable by analytic means, and we have to resort to approximations or numerical methods. Since every atom has a different charge of the nucleus and a different number of electrons, you get that the shape of the orbitals is a function not only of the nucleus but also of the electrons, in particular the inner ones which "screen" the nucleus from the viewpoint of the outer ones.

Comment: "The shape of the orbitals is a function of the nucleus and the electrons." Awesome. Am I right in saying that every element has similar but not the same orbitals at each level and also that elements with smaller nuclei are less likely to have electrons in the orbitals further out from the nucleus?